# How to use NMSSH in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I developed a simple IOs app to control a Raspberry Pi through SSH using [NMSSH](https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH) few month ago, this app is developped with obj-c and I would like to devellop alost the same in Swift so i import the NMSSH library the same and I follow [this](http://michal.codes/integrating-cocoapods-with-a-swift-project/) to import nmssh with bridging so I can use the library in my swift file but i wan tto compile I have 117 error because xCode see NMSSH file like swift files and not obj-c files and I don't have any idea why or how to solve this.
Sorry if that's a simple question but I try to learn Swift and as a french it's not pretty simple with all documentation in Engloish. Thanks.

EDIT:

[image]
[image: Here is example of my error]

Comment: at the least, you should show us what are the compilation error messages

Comment: I had screenshot in the main post, there is almost only "expected a type" error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First follow the instruction in iOS Developer library about using [Swift with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77).
Second include:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

and then NMSSH import

```
#import <NMSSH/NMSSH.h>
```

in your `Bridging header` file

I am new with this framework but it seems like the Foundation contain information/definition of primitive objects.

Also check this answer in more detail: [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: Worked for me. Its about headers