# Execute SSH via Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ssh

I m looking for a way to run ssh commands from iOS is there a simple and basic way?
As NSTask() is not available on iOS, its just for a need to send a 2 lines of ssh to a RaspberryPi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible workaround could be using the Objective C **[NMSSH](https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH)** library by following the guide in **[this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110980/how-to-use-nmssh-in-swift#answer-27396658)** . Further, maybe you should also take a look at "**[Adding Swift bridging header](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/)**" (if using NMSSH is an option) as referenced in following **[issue](https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH/issues/104)**

Comment: ah thanks :-) damn why google didnt bring up this lib for me :)

Comment: @FabianBoulegue You're welcome! Well, since I've never used it with Swift (that's why I came up with this library) it was not that hard to find it. I think NMSSH don't appear in search results if you use SSH and Swift without any further refers to Objective C or NMSSH. ^^

Comment: ok need to look at this later :-) as i m not 100% familiar with using ObjC Frameworks in Swift, the bridging header isnt the problem :)!

Comment: if you want you could check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271828/nmssh-does-not-connect-with-swift