# How to fix failure establishing connection NMSSH

Tags: swift, nmssh

How do I use NMSSH in Swift?
When I execute the code below, I get these messages in my debug console:

```
2019-11-14 19:15:53.830479+0100 unLock[49480:480479] NMSSH: Start 192.168.178.97 resolution
2019-11-14 19:15:53.832950+0100 unLock[49480:480481] NMSSH: Socket connection to 192.168.178.97 on port 44 failed with reason -1, trying next address...
2019-11-14 19:15:53.833005+0100 unLock[49480:480481] NMSSH: Failure establishing socket connection
2019-11-14 19:15:53.833047+0100 unLock[49480:480481] NMSSH: Disconnected
```

The code:

```
let session = NMSSHSession(host: "192.168.178.97:44", andUsername: "root")
        session.connect()
        if session.isConnected == true{
            session.authenticate(byPassword: "alpine")
            //if session.isAuthorized == true {
                session.channel.execute("killall SpringBoard", error: nil)
                print("killed Springboard")
            //}
        }
```

What I've done is allowing arbitrary Loads in App Transport Security because I thought the problem may be that the ssh server isn't HTTPS, but it did not help. The fact that I try to SSH into an iPhone isn't the cause Haswell, as I tried it with a Raspberry Pi, same result. Also don't mind port 44 as it is the correct port for checkra1n.

Comment: You can see similar type problem here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110980/how-to-use-nmssh-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110980/how-to-use-nmssh-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can see similar type problem here.

[How to use NMSSH in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110980/how-to-use-nmssh-in-swift)

Also Read the Readme file for NMSSH and setup this framework using podfile.

```
pod 'NMSSH'
```

**Read Documentation here**

https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH